# How to append the list(str) in text file into a 2 dimensional list in python

Tags: python, list

`fruits.txt`

`['banana', 'apple']`
`['durian','dragon fruit']`

```
fruits=[["banana", "apple"],["durian","dragon fruit"]]  
with open ("fruits.txt", "w") as fruit:
    for f in fruits:
        fruit.write(str(f))
        fruit.write("\n")

with open ("fruits.txt", "rt") as f:
    for fruit in f:
        fruits.append(fruit.rstrip("\n"))
```

Wanted output: `fruits=[["banana", "apple"],["durian","dragon fruit"]]`

What I got: `fruits=["["banana", "apple"]","["durian","dragon fruit"]"]`

*But I always get the syntax error:
Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)* (isn't reproducible)

May I know how to solve this?

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you add your code which throws the exception?

Comment: `fruits=[["banana", "apple"],["durian","dragon fruit"]]`

`with open ("fruits.txt", "w") as fruit:           
        for f in fruits:                           
            fruit.write(str(f))
            fruit.write("\n")
with open ("fruits.txt", "rt") as f:           
        for fruit in f:                           
            fruits.append(fruit.rstrip("\n"))`

fruits.txt
['banana', 'apple'] 
['durian','dragon fruit']

Wanted output:
`fruits=[["banana", "apple"],["durian","dragon fruit"]]`
What I got:
`fruits=["["banana", "apple"]","["durian","dragon fruit"]"]`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I cannot reproduce your error and you append your read out values to your initial list which produce `[['banana', 'apple'], ['durian', 'dragon fruit'], "['banana', 'apple']", "['durian', 'dragon fruit']"]`

Here some ideas how you can handle this:

```py
import csv
import json

fruits = [['banana', 'apple'],['durian','dragon fruit']]

# in my opinion this is the correct way to write the file here by using csv.writer() and csv.reader()
with open ('fruits1.txt', 'w') as file_write:
  file = csv.writer(file_write)
  file.writerows(fruits)

# output:
# banana,apple
# durian,dragon fruit

# how to read fruits1.txt
new_fruits1 = []
with open ('fruits1.txt', 'r', newline='\n') as file_read:
  content = csv.reader(file_read, delimiter=',')
  for line in content:
    new_fruits1.append(line)

print(type(new_fruits1)) # >> <class 'list'>
print(new_fruits1) # >> [['banana', 'apple'], ['durian', 'dragon fruit']] # your expected output ;)


# your way to write the file: you store your nested list ad a string
with open ('fruits2.txt', 'w') as file_write:
  file_write.write(str(fruits))

# output:
# [['banana', 'apple'], ['durian', 'dragon fruit']]

# how to read fruits2.txt worst way (replace all unneeded chars) - DEFINITELY NOT RECOMMENDED WAY
new_fruits2 = []
with open ('fruits2.txt', 'r', newline='\n') as file_read:
  content = file_read.read()
  print(type(content)) # >> <class 'str'>
  print(content) # >> [['banana', 'apple'], ['durian', 'dragon fruit']]

  # it is complicated to extract this to get a proper list:
  content_split = content.split('], [') # to get later to parts of list entries
  for con in content_split:
    prepared_content = con.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('\'', '')
    new_fruits2 += [prepared_content.split(', ')]

print(type(new_fruits2)) # >> <class 'list'>
print(new_fruits2) # >> [['banana', 'apple'], ['durian', 'dragon fruit']]

# how to read fruits2.txt with using json - MY RECOMMENDATION
new_fruits2 = []
with open ('fruits2.txt', 'r', newline='\n') as file_read:
  content = file_read.read()
  print(type(content)) # >> <class 'str'>
  new_fruits2 = json.loads(content.replace('\'', '"'))
  
print(type(new_fruits2)) # >> <class 'list'>
print(new_fruits2) # >> [['banana', 'apple'], ['durian', 'dragon fruit']]

# how to read fruits2.txt with using eval()
new_fruits2 = []
with open ('fruits2.txt', 'r', newline='\n') as file_read:
  content = file_read.read()
  new_fruits2 = eval(content)

print(type(new_fruits2)) # >> <class 'list'>
print(new_fruits2) # >> [['banana', 'apple'], ['durian', 'dragon fruit']]
```